# Control V4L2/VB2 Buffer Allocation?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, v4l2

I am trying to write a V4L2 compliant driver for a special camera device i have, but the device doesn't seem particularly friendly with V4L2's buffer system.  Instead of the separately allocated buffers, it wants a single contiguous block of memory capable of holding a set # of buffers (usually 4), and it then provides a status register telling you which is the latest (updated after each frame is DMA'ed to the host).  So it basically needs only a single large DMA allocated memory chunk to work with, not 4 most-likely separated.

How can I use this with V4L?  Everything I see about `VIDIOC_CREATE_BUFS`, `VIDIOC_REQBUFS` and such does internal allocation of the buffers, and I can't get anything V4L-based (like `qv4l2` to work without a successful `QBUF` and `DQBUF` that uses their internal structure.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for completion, I finally found a solution in the "meye" driver.  I removed everything VB2 and wrote my own reqbuf, querybuf, qbuf, and dqbuf, along with my own mmap routines to handle the allocation.  And it all works!